# How to display diffrent images using if function after pressing a button

Tags: javascript, html

For my collage assignment i need to create a html webpage where if you press the button yes it displays a number and a corresponding image. i have figured out how to create the random number but cannot get the corresponding image to show up when the button in pressed. i am very new to this and any help would be appreciated

This is the java script

```js
function randomNumber() {
  var ranNumgen = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
}

console.log("randomNumber");
if ("number" == 1) {
  document.getElementById('img1').src = "image/dice1.jpg";
} else if ("number" == 2) {
  document.getElementById('img1').src = "image/dice2.jpg";
} else if ("number" == 3) {
  document.getElementById("img1").src = "image/dice3.jpg"
} else if ("number" == 4) {
  document.getElementById("img1").src = "image/dice4.jpg";
} else if ("number" == 5) {
  document.getElementById("img1").src = "image/dice5.jpg";
} else if ("number" == 6) {
  document.getElementById("img1").src = "image/dice6.jpg";
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title></title>
  <button id="b" onclick="ranNumgen()"> Yes </button>
  <button onclick="Num2button()">No</button>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="number"> </p>


And this is all my code 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <button id="b" onclick="ranNumgen()">   Yes </button>
    <button onclick="Num2button()">No</button>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="number"> </p>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function randomNumber() {
        var ranNumgen = Math.floor((Math.random() *6) +1);      
}
    
    console.log("randomNumber");
    if ("number" ==1 ) {
        document.getElementById('img1').src ="image/dice1.jpg";
    }

   else if ("number" ==2) {
    document.getElementById('img1').src ="image/dice2.jpg";
   }
   else if ("number"==3) {
    document.getElementById("img1").src="image/dice3.jpg"
   } 
   else if ("number"==4) {
document.getElementById("img1").src="image/dice4.jpg";
   }
   else if ("number"==5) {
        document.getElementById("img1").src="image/dice5.jpg";
   }
   else if ("number"==6) {
        document.getElementById("img1").src="image/dice6.jpg";
   }

        function Num2button() {
        var button2 = "Are you sure"
        alert(button2);
            }


    </script>
    




</body>
                    
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show every code you have? I found too many errors on your code.

Comment: @PedroFelgueiras just added all code their now

Comment: All that code could be reduced to `document.getElementById('img1').src  = "image/dice" + number + ".jpg"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your logic to assign the picture in your *randomNumber* function, the best would be to rename it to something like *generateRandomPicture*.

Then you need an  element with the id you have specified and
also I would recommend that you use an eventListener instead of doing the inline scripting.

You can add .addEventListener() to your element.

```
document.getElementById('b').addEventListener('click', randomNumber);
```

```js
document.getElementById('b').addEventListener('click', randomNumber);

function randomNumber() {
  let number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);

  if (number == 1) {
    document.getElementById('img1').src = "image/dice1.jpg";
  } else if (number == 2) {
    document.getElementById('img1').src = "image/dice2.jpg";
  } else if (number == 3) {
    document.getElementById("img1").src = "image/dice3.jpg"
  } else if (number == 4) {
    document.getElementById("img1").src = "image/dice4.jpg";
  } else if (number == 5) {
    document.getElementById("img1").src = "image/dice5.jpg";
  } else if (number == 6) {
    document.getElementById("img1").src = "image/dice6.jpg";
  }

}
```

```html
<head>
  <title></title>

</head>

<body>
  <p id="number"> </p>
  <img id="img1"></img>
  <button id="b"> Yes </button>
  <button onclick="Num2button()">No</button>
</body>
```

Comment: @antoki1558 you are welcome, if you think it was helpful mark it as accepted the button below down up voting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware that the question is already answered and that you are new to this but this is a more scalable approach and looks a bit cleaner.

**NOTE:** This snippet assumes the images in the array in the correct order, from 1 to N.

```js
let images = [
    'https://via.placeholder.com/10',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/20',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/30',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/40',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/50',
]

function setRandomImage() {
    let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
    document.getElementById('img').src = images[index];
    document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = index + 1;
}
```

```html
<img id="img"></img>
<p id="num"></p>
<button onclick="setRandomImage()">Yes</button>
<button>No</button>
```

As per **epascarello's** comment, this does not rely on the order of the images but they do have to be in the array.

```js
var images = [
    'https://via.placeholder.com',
    'https://via.placeholder.com',
    'https://via.placeholder.com',
    'https://via.placeholder.com',
    'https://via.placeholder.com',
]
function setRandomImage() {
    let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length) + 1;
    document.getElementById('img').src  = images[index - 1] + '/' + index + '0';
    document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = index;
}
```

```html
<img id="img"></img>
<p id="num"></p>
<button onclick="setRandomImage()">Yes</button>
<button>No</button>
```

And if you always have a static number of images which are properly named you can even do away with the images array.

```js
function setRandomImage() {
    let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    document.getElementById('img').src  = 'https://via.placeholder.com/' + rand + '0';
    document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = rand;
}
```

```html
<img id="img"></img>
<p id="num"></p>
<button onclick="setRandomImage()">Yes</button>
<button>No</button>
```